# Git very first steps

Tags: git

I am trying to get familiar with git. But I am a rookie developer and I need help with my first steps with git. I don't know where to start. Can you help?

I have a server that is hosting my website, which is git-enabled and where I have SSH access. There I created a directory

```
mkdir mystuff.git
```

Then I changed into that directory

```
cd mystuff.git
```

and ran

```
git --bare init
```

Nothing more. The URL now is http://my.site/mystuff.git

On my local PC I have installed git for Windows but done nothing more. I have two directories that I want to 'import' into that git infrastructure: A directory with powershell scripts. They are located in

```
c:\users\richard\prog\powershell
```

and a book (txt files, each file represents a chapter) I started to write recently. This is located under

```
c:\users\richard\documents\book-about-stuff
```

How do I get the content of the two directories onto my web server? I read about 'local ropositories'. Are my two directories these 'local repositories'? Or do I have to create another local subdir with the help of the local git for Windows software? I tried to read the tutorial under http://schacon.github.io/git/gittutorial.html but it helped me not. Is 'local' my local PC and 'remote' the server under http: //my.site? Is 'master' my first dirctory and 'branch' my second directory? Maybe I only need help with the wording.

I don' want to work with Github because I don't code anything for the public at the moment.

Comment: If you're not coding anything public, why do you feel the need for a remote repository?  You can work with Git entirely offline.

Comment: If you're only interested in revision control, then you can use git without a remote repository.

Comment: @Makoto: probably for a backup and a possibility to synchronize work done on multiple machines

Comment: to begining with git, try https://try.github.io/ and https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git. i hope it helps...

Comment: @Makoto A remote repository can help you if you trash your local repository.  Also, even if you're not doing anything public doesn't mean you don't have multiple machines. The answer to "how do I get these directories onto the web server" could be partially solved with having an upstream repo accessible to both the web server and the development machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginnings with `Git` can be hard, especially if you haven't used a
[DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) or
even any [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)
before. This answer doesn't aim to be a complete `Git` tutorial. I
will just try to answer your questions and get you up and running with
`Git`. You have to read a whole book on `Git` and practice it to
really learn it just like anything else.

> How do I get the content of the two directories onto my web server?

You need to *upload* it to the remote repository that you have already
created correctly. In `Git` it is done using `push` command. More
about it later. In `Git`
only a few operations are done locally and `push` is one of
them. Majority of operations are done locally and can be executed
offline. This is the power of `Git`.

> Are my two directories these 'local repositories'?

Not until you create a new `Git` repository inside them but, yes, they
will be.

> Or do I have to create another local subdir with the help of the local
>   git for Windows software?

No, you can create a new `Git` repository in an existing
directory. There is no need to make a new one. To create a `Git`
repository in an existing directory enter this directory and do:

```
$ git init
```

Now you need to add files that you want `Git` to track. If you want to
keep all of the files under revision control do:

```
$ git add -A
```

or do `git add <FILE>` for all individual files. Now you are ready to
make the first commit:

```
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now we can push the first commit to the server:

```
$ git remote add origin http://my.site/mystuff.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

> Is 'local' my local PC and 'remote' the server under http:
>   //my.site?

Now yes.

> Is 'master' my first dirctory and 'branch' my second directory?

Now, `master` is the default name that `Git` gives to the first
branch. `Git` is renowned for its branching capabilities.

> I don' want to work with Github because I don't code anything for
>   the public at the moment.

If you have no time to manage a remote `Git` repository but you feel
you need it for the reasons I given in a comment under your question
consider using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). It provides
[private repos](https://bitbucket.org/plans) for free.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might make two repositories.

Git for windows gives you a bash interface and a graphical user interface.

Just like you have initialised a git repository on your server, you could initialize repositories, one for your powershell scripts, and one for your book, in the same directories where they live.

Then go back to your server and git clone those new repositories.

git clone ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to setup a remote git repo on your own server, for that you can read (all the chapter) http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols. Also you may read the entire book http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/.

But for a rokie in git a better solution it's to use some other ready solution, like bitbucket which requires no setup, and also provides private repos.